# make can't find files

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to install a go package with `make`, but it returns the following:

```
dan@dan-netbook:~/GoMySQL$ make  
Makefile:1: :/home/dan/.go/go/src/Make.inc: No such file or directory  
Makefile:17: :/home/dan/.go/go/src/Make.pkg: No such file or directory  
make: *** No rule to make target `:/home/dan/.go/go/src/Make.pkg'.  Stop.
```

but the missing files are present if I run `ls`:

```
dan@dan-netbook:~/GoMySQL$ ls /home/dan/.go/go/src/  
all.bash       env.bash  make.bash  Make.common  quietgcc.bash   
all-qemu.bash  lib9      Make.ccmd  Make.inc     run.bash  
clean.bash     libbio    Make.clib  Make.pkg     sudo.bash  
cmd            libmach   Make.cmd   pkg          version.bash
```

Why is this?

**Edit:** Makefile is:

```
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.inc  

TARG=mysql  
GOFILES=mysql.go\  
   types.go\  
   const.go\  
   error.go\  
   password.go\  
   reader.go\  
   writer.go\  
   packet.go\  
   convert.go\  
   handler.go\  
   result.go\  
   statement.go  

 include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```

Comment: @mu is too short: I'm guessing it's assigned as `GOROOT=:/path`, i.e. `:=` is misstyped as `=:`

Comment: Oh, `GOROOT` is assigned outside the Makefile? Then my next guess is `export GOROOT=$EMPTY_VAR:$GOROOT`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this error message:

```
 Makefile:1: :/home/dan/.go/go/src/Make.inc: No such file or directory  
             ^
```

I'm a bit surprised by the indicated colon.

We need to see what GOROOT is set to in the Makefile, which is not too easy. I don't know much about building go packages, but from the command line, try:

```
echo $GOROOT
```

and report what that prints.

Then try changing the Makefile. At the very beginning of it, add:

```
foobar:
    echo $(GOROOT)
```

where the echo line must be indented with  a tab, not spaces, and tell us what that produces.

Comment: Thanks. That led me to the answer. I don't really know my way around .bashrc yet and had added the colon before the directory, thinking that was the correct syntax. Removing the colon in .bashrc solved the  problem.